# TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'

Tags: python, pandas, plotly-dash

I am trying to disable a button when Click until a process finishes and then enable it again. Here's an outline of the steps:

1. user press button
2. button gets disabled
3. script starts to run
4. script ends to run
5. button is enabled
6. another element gets updated with script output

or I just perform `dcc.loading` on this case.

Here's my code:

```
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
from Missing_relation_All import my_DB_func


external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Button('Create Missing Relation Script', id='button', disabled=False),
    # other element
    html.Div(id='other-element'),
    # trigger div
    html.Div(id='trigger', children=0, style=dict(display='none'))
])


@app.callback(
    Output('button', 'disabled'),
    [Input('button', 'n_clicks'),
     Input('trigger', 'children')])
def trigger_function(n_clicks, trigger):
    context = dash.callback_context.triggered[0]['prop_id'].split('.')[0]
    context_value = dash.callback_context.triggered[0]['value']

    # if the button triggered the function
    if context == 'button':
        # if the function is triggered at app load, this will not disable the button
        # but if the function is triggered by clicking the button, this disables the button as expected
        if n_clicks > 0:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    # if the element function completed and triggered the function
    else:
        # if the function is triggered at app load, this will not disable the button
        # but if the function is triggered by the function finishing, this enables the button as expected
        return False


@app.callback(
    [Output('other-element', 'children'),
     Output('trigger', 'children')],
    [Input('button', 'n_clicks')])
def update_element(n_clicks):
    my_DB_func()
    return (
        'my element value',
        1  # update the trigger value
    )



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

So when I am trying to run the app I get this error:

```
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'

File "C:\Users\haroo501\PycharmProjects\My_Check_Missing_Relation_Tool\newbuttontest.py", line 32, in trigger_function
if n_clicks > 0:
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\haroo501\PycharmProjects\My_Check_Missing_Relation_Tool\newbuttontest.py", line 32, in trigger_function
    if n_clicks > 0:
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

So what do I need to do after click the button make it Freeze or disabled till:

```
Process finished with exit code -1
```

after finish the process or finish the script which is based on the `def`?

Comment: `n_clicks` isn't a number, it's `None`, so your code doesn't run

Comment: @Juan C I tried to follow up this question https://community.plot.ly/t/button-disable-enable-while-performing-action/23729/2

Comment: Mmmm... been a long time since the last time I used `dash`, so I'm not sure. You should tag it as a `dash` question, I don't know why you tagged it as `sqlalchemy` or `hyphen`

Comment: @JuanC  I updated question, that's because I used pandas and sql-alchemy modules in the `def` function :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this like this way when Changed this part:

```
        if n_clicks > 0:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

to this:

```
        if n_clicks is None:
            raise dash.exceptions.PreventUpdate
        else:
            return True
```

and this part:

```
@app.callback(
    [Output('other-element', 'children'),
     Output('trigger', 'children')],
    [Input('button', 'n_clicks')])
def update_element(n_clicks):
    my_DB_func()
    return (
        'my element value',
        1  # update the trigger value
    )
```

to this:

```
def update_element(n_clicks):
    if n_clicks == True:
        my_DB_func()
    return (
        'my element value',
        1 # update the trigger value
    )
```

as the final code will be something like this:

```
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
from Missing_relation_All import my_DB_func
from dash.exceptions import PreventUpdate

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Button('Create Missing Relation Script', id='button', disabled=False),
    # other element
    html.Div(id='other-element'),
    # trigger div
    html.Div(id='trigger', children=0, style=dict(display='none'))
])


@app.callback(
    Output('button', 'disabled'),
    [Input('button', 'n_clicks'),
     Input('trigger', 'children')])
def trigger_function(n_clicks, trigger):
    context = dash.callback_context.triggered[0]['prop_id'].split('.')[0]
    context_value = dash.callback_context.triggered[0]['value']

    # if the button triggered the function
    if context == 'button':
        # if the function is triggered at app load, this will not disable the button
        # but if the function is triggered by clicking the button, this disables the button as expected
        if n_clicks is None:
            raise dash.exceptions.PreventUpdate
        else:
            return True
    # if the element function completed and triggered the function
    else:
        # if the function is triggered at app load, this will not disable the button
        # but if the function is triggered by the function finishing, this enables the button as expected
        return False


@app.callback(
    [Output('other-element','children'),
     Output('trigger','children')],
    [Input('button','n_clicks')])
def update_element(n_clicks):
    if n_clicks == True:
        my_DB_func()
    return (
        'my element value',
        1 # update the trigger value
    )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```